# script GNU to install kaggle API

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

This is my first time trying to download a dataset ('train.csv') from the API.
I am currently trying to install in ubuntu the API with the instruction `sudo pip install kaggle-cli` but it's not being possible.
Error: `pip: order not found`

Is there any other option?
I want to work then with GNU (awk, bash,....)

The [information](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api) I found is not being enough to solve the problem.

Could someone let me know how to install it?

Thanks.

Comment: As said in documentation: `Ensure you have Python 3 and the package manager pip installed.`

Comment: @Toto, and isn't there any option of getting the API without Python3?

Comment: @Toto, Python3 already install and errors remain

Comment: Have you installed `pip`?

Comment: no. there are some error arising too

Comment: From the doc: `Installations done through the root user (i.e. sudo pip install kaggle) will not work correctly unless you understand what you're doing. Even then, they still might not work. User installs are strongly recommended in the case of permissions errors.`

Comment: @Toto. I read this. and now what? I tried the several options there are shown and didn't work. that's why I'm writing

Comment: What happens without `sudo`?